# Netsuite Sitebuilder My Reference Checkout 3D secuer

Tags: netsuite

I'm creating a new sitebuilder website, and have successfully set up "My Reference Checkout". However, we haven't been able to get it integrated with 3D secure, meaning that no customers can check out (unless we remove all the security, which we don't want to do).

Looking at netsuite's documentation on SuiteAnswers [here](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27511/related/1), it gives us some very generic pointers about how we have to create some .ss and .js files, and modify some existing front-end code in Custom checkout. However, AFAICT the examples are not useful - they don't tell us where to put these ss & js files, where to modify the front end, and some of the files don't even seen to be related etc.

Does anyone have any better documentation for how to integrate with 3D secure, or please can someone point me in the right direction?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Same question for latest SCA/SiteBuilder Extensions. Did you have any success?

Comment: Regretfully not. I tried the netsuite forums but no-one was helpful. I feel it's a bit of a cartel - why provide documentation for developers when you should pay $10,000 (from memory) for a video tutorial series from netsuite itself, or just pay them (or ex-employees in the form of consultants) to do it for you :(

Comment: Somebody else mentioned a video. Do you know what that's called I may have access.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, and old, so you may have found the answer, but I would recommend reading and searching at this resource: https://devsc.publishpath.com.  It uses your netsuite login and password. There is a blog post at this location: http://devsc.publishpath.com/Default.aspx?p=2079436&Add=Show+Post&Key=Show+Post&ContentID=5226425&PostID=1200364&shortcut=developing-your-first-custom-suitecommerce-advanced-module-part-1 that goes through setting up the reference cart if you are using it.

Outside of that here is a brief overview.  The SSP and SS pages are setup using a utility in Netsuite under Setup/Site Builder/(Sub-Heading-Web Site Management)SSP applications.  Here you set where in the Netsuite file system your SSP and SS pages are.  The files themselves should be somewhere in your file structure under your hosting root.  They load in order of precedence and have to be deployed. For certain activities (like logging in or checking out) you need to set up touchpoints.